# Highstock - Remove axis and series dynamically

Tags: angular, highcharts

In this example [Adding Y-Axis dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658249/adding-y-axis-dynamically) we can add axis dynamically. How to remove an axis dynamically on a button click. Is there any method like this? 
In highstock api reference I could not find any example. Please help me

Comment: reload it and dont pass that data

Comment: I want that on a button click  Saurabh Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done using this code:

```
  $('#remove').click(function() {
    chart.series[1].remove(false);
    chart.get('rainfall-axis').remove(true);
  });
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/tm3vq1be/ (first add then remove)

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#remove
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#remove